# Redirecting Issue

Tags: redirect

About a month ago I renamed a couple of pages and then edited my `.htaccess` file with the following:

```
Redirect 301 truck-hire/johannesburg http://kempston.co.za/truck-hire/truck-hire-johannesburg
```

I've just discovered that when I browse to the old URL I get redirected from:

```
kempston.co.za/truck-hire/johannesburg
```

to:

```
kempston.co.za/employment-solutions/johannesburg/
```

instead of:

```
kempston.co.za/truck-hire/truck-hire-johannesburg
```

I've removed the redirects in the `.htaccess` file but it's still doing it!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after much poking around I decided to try reinserting the redirects and it worked again! In my poking I discovered that my browser (Chrome) was caching my `.htaccess` page so what I was seeing was different to what was actually saved in the file. Not sure if it's an issue with the host (Hetzner) or my browser.